# limit of indicator function, if exists

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function below:

$f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, x = 1, \hfill \frac{1}2,\frac{1}3,\frac{1}4,...\\  0,\hfill otherwise\end{cases}$

I want to find for which values of $x$ the function $f$ has a limit, and to find its value. I supose there are points where the limit does not exist, for those points, what is the formal proof i should deduce? $f$ is not continuous on zero.

Comment: What do you mean by "for which values of $x$ the function $f$ has a limit"?

Comment: Also I do not see the connection to your title. Maybe you can give a rigorous version of what you want to ask and what you tried so far to tackle the problem.

Comment: And also welcome on math.stackexchange :)

Comment: My intuition points out that for every "n" natural number which satisfies{1/n} the function has a limit 1 (its its value can be changed) by opening punctured neighborhood around each x0. So, improving my choice i get that each x inside the neighborhood will be equal one , and for x0 = 0 the limit will be equal 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer**

- Limit $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ doesn't exist.
- If $x_0\neq 0$ then $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$.

**Solution**

- Let $x_n=\frac 1n$, $y_n=\frac{\sqrt 2}n$. Then $x_n,y_n\to 0$, $f(x_n)=1\to 1$, $f(y_n)=0\to 0$. Therefore from Heine defnition of limits, there aren't any limit in $0$.
- If $x_0\neq 0$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in (x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)\setminus\{x_0\}$. Therefore  $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=0$.

How to deal with the case $x=0$ without sequences: for any $\delta>0$ in the set $(-\delta,\delta)\setminus\{0\}$ there are points with value $0$ and value $1$. The function doesn't satisfy the Cauchy condition: $$\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\text{ exists }\iff\\\forall (\varepsilon>0)\,\exists(\delta>0)\forall(x_1,x_2\in D_f): 0<|x_1-x_0|,|x_2-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x_1)-f(x_2)|<\varepsilon.$$

How to find the proper $\delta$:

- If $x_0<0$ then $\delta:=|x_0|$
- If $x_0>0$ and $x_0=1/k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$ then $\delta:=\min(\frac 1k-\frac 1{k+1},\frac 1{k-1}-\frac 1k)=\frac 1k-\frac 1{k+1}$.
- If $0<x_0\leq 1$ and $x_0\notin\{1,1/2,1/3,\ldots\}$ then $\frac 1{k+1}<x_0<\frac 1k$. Then $\delta:=\min(\frac 1k-x_0,x_0-\frac 1{k+1})$.
- If $x_0>1$ then $\delta:=x_0-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please elaborate why did you define y_n as it is? is it arbitrary choice within the given bound? I think im missing the part of defining the delta, it will help a lot if you could show it in your proof. Then i will except it as answer. Kindly regards. Is there an option to prove the given function using non Heine definition of limits?

Comment: I defined $y_n$ this way so that $y_n\to 0$ and $y_n\notin\{1/2,1/3,1/4,\ldots\}$. I could choose another sequence of irrational numbers or try some sequence of rational numbers but then I should be more careful.

Comment: @Caveira, look now at the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)